# Why is Carl "a disgrace" to the military academy in Season 10?

Tags: plot-explanation, shameless

In season 9 of the US version of *Shameless*, Carl decided to join a military academy. He was doing pretty well - with a typical Gallagher charisma he manages to get respect from the fellow students and quickly takes a leading role commanding other cadets.

Comes season 10 and Carl is in school jail and the principal calls him "a disgrace to the school" and he apparently will never be able to join the army ([which would be probably impossible in the first place, since Carl has a juvenile criminal record](https://www.thebalancecareers.com/can-a-juvenile-felon-enlist-3354071)). There is a brief mention that Carl was defending a "trans" student from hazing (although he thought that this student was just "transferring to a different school", not "transgender"), but that wouldn't put him into trouble, probably even quite contrary, he would be rewarded for that. So where did this "disgrace" come from?

So what has happened between those seasons?

Comment: Isn't this simply a case of the show's writers being awful and clueless?

Comment: @BCdotWEB possibly.... but Gallaghers f*ing things up when it seems that they are heading in the right direction is THE theme of this show, so one could expect some sort of a flashback or at least explanation